# Test class for Trigger and web service class

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices, unit-test

This is my trigger, for sending SMS when account owner is changed

```
trigger sms on Account (before insert,before update) {

    for(Account acc:trigger.new)
    {
        if(acc.Status__c=='Qualified' && acc.ownerid != trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).ownerid)
        //if I include "&& acc.ownerid != trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).ownerid" i'm not getting test coverage
        {
            user u=[SELECT Alias,Id,MobilePhone,Name,Phone FROM User where Id=: acc.OwnerId];
            sendsms.sendsms1(u.MobilePhone,u.name);
            //sendsms.sendsms1(acc.Phone1__c,acc.name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class for the above trigger, if i perform any DML operation(insert and update) my method is not passing. I mean I will get 100% test coverage if i don't include 
`&& acc.ownerid != trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id).ownerid` in the above trigger.

```
@isTest
public class sms1 {

    static testmethod void testsms() {
        Account acc= new Account();
        acc.name='Acc1';
        acc.Status__c='Qualified';
        acc.ownerid='0059000000101C6';

        Account acc1= new Account();
        acc1.name='Acc1';
        acc1.Status__c='Qualified';
        acc1.ownerid='005O0000001VQSD';    
    }
}
```

This is my apex class to send SMS from 3rd party application

```
public class sendsms {
   @Future(callout=true)
    public static void sendsms1(string mobile,string name) {

   // list<account> acc=[SELECT Id,Phone FROM Account where id=:conId];

       String Username ='xxxxxx@xxx.com';
       String Password = 'xxxxxx';
       String TempID='11111' ;
       String MobileNo=mobile;
       String F1=name;
       String SenderID = 'XXXXX';
       String F2= '8-09-2013';
       String F3= '07-09-2013';
       String postData = 'username=' +Username + '&pass=' + Password + '&dest_mobileno=' + MobileNo +'&senderid=' + SenderID + '&tempid=' + TempID+'&F1=' + F1+ '&F2=' + F2+ '&F3=' + F3;

       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setEndpoint('http://124.65.33.43/blank/sms/user/urlsmstemp.php?'+postdata);
       req.setMethod('GET');
       system.debug(req);
       Http http = new Http();
       HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
       system.debug(res);
    }
}
```

Can anyone save me from this problem. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: oldMap used in trigger would not work on insert trigger

Answer (score 5):

Well, I see many things wrong here

1. **Trigger.oldmap** is not available on Before Insert: `trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id)`
2. **Account.Id** is not available on before Insert: `trigger.oldmap.get(acc.id)`
3. **Avoid SOQL within a loop**, that is not Bulk-Safe!:  `user u=[SELECT Alias,Id,MobilePhone,Name,Phone FROM User where Id=: acc.OwnerId];`
4. You must **insert or update** the created account in the Test to **fire** the trigger event.
5. You also need a **[HTTPCalloutMock](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)** in order to test the `sendsms1` method
6. Probably you should add the `Test.start/stop` to cover the future method.
7. You have to **create the user** in the Test method, avoid this: `acc1.ownerid='005O0000001VQSD';`